# GNURadio 3.8 QPSK : Hard time to recover the right symbols/data

Tags: digital-communications, gnuradio, qpsk, usrp

Cheers, I am demodulating a QPSK signal on GNURadio, the data transmitted is a known HEX file with the "1ACFFC1D" foreword every 124 bytes, to check if the demodulation is a success, it contains ascii code saying "Bonjour :)" indefinitely to spot easily an error.
I also compare the bits in a time sink. The signal is modulated on a separated system and is transmitted to the the USRP via a coax cable.
[image: hex file demodulated (no foreword anymore)]
The constellation seems neat to me and the file uses all the symbols to trigger all the points in the constellation. However when I launch the flow-graph, the foreword isn't always recognized and I have to reload the costas loop manually and then everything hooks up and the demod is fine.
[image: Plots the constellation and time sinks]
Everything is fine in the photo above, but the constellation is looking the same when bits are not recovered.
First I thought that the points of the constellation were maybe shifted so I mapped the constellation with four different shifts and tried to grab the foreword for each one but it did not work :
[image: The flow-graph]

If you have any ideas or explanation of why it does not hook up at each run I would be very grateful because I am kind of lost about it.

Have a nice day !

Comment: what you show is a screenshot from GNU Radio 3.8, 3.9 or 3.10, definitely not GNU Radio 3.7!

Comment: Yes you are right thank you, it is 3.8, I made a typo haha